# Parseval's formula in CNNs

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, machine-learning, neural-networks

In [Intriguing properties of neural networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6199) on page 9 it says that

> If $ W $ denotes a generic 4-tensor, implementing a convolutional layer with $ C $ input features, $ D $ output features, support $ N \times N $ and spatial stride $ \Delta $:
> $$
> Wx = \left\{ \sum_{c=1}^C x_c \star w_{c,d}(n_1 \Delta, n_2 \Delta); d = 1, \ldots, D \right\} \, ,
> $$
> where $ x_c $ denotes the $ c $-th input feature, and $ w_{c,d} $ is the spatial kernel corresponding to input feature $ c $ and output feature $ d $, by applying **Parseval's formula** we obtain that its operator norm is given by
> $$
> \| W \| = \sup_{\xi \in [0, N \Delta^{-1})^2} \| A(\xi) \| \, ,
> $$
> where $ A(\xi) $ is a $ D \times (C \cdot \Delta^2) $ matrix whose rows are
> $$
> A(\xi)_d = \left( \Delta^{-2} \widehat{w_{c,d}} (\xi + l \cdot N \cdot \Delta^{-1}); c = 1 \cdot C, l = (0 \ldots \Delta-1)^2 \right) \, ,
> $$
> and $ \widehat{w_{c,d}} $ is the 2-D Fourier transform of $ w_{c,d} $:
> $$
> \widehat{w_{c,d}} = \sum_{u \in [0, N)^2} w_{c,d}(u) e^{- 2 \pi i (u \cdot \xi) / N^2} \, .
> $$

My question is: which Parseval's formula is being referred here and how to use it to derive the equation for $ \| W \| $?
I know about [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) and [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem), but I do not see how either of these could be applied.